# Disable Left/Right Scrolling on Magic Mouse with Google Calendar

Tags: macos, mouse

I am a first time Magic Mouse user.  I *love* the vertical scrolling on web pages.  However, on Google Calendar, scrolling left-to-right makes the calendar move forward and back between months.  I'm *constantly* accidentally scrolling my calendar with the Magic Mouse.

Is there I way I can tell the Magic Mouse to **not do** the left/right scroll/swipe thing, but to still do the up/down scroll/swipe thing?  One a per application basis?  Or some other solution I'm not thinking of?  This [uber complaint thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/O2fpZq36otA) makes it seem like it's not possible to disable this feature in Google Calendar (although I'm happy to be corrected there).  10.12.5, if it matters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are tons of very old threads on the Google Forums around this but I finally turned up one which linked to this Chrome plugin which kills the scrolling in Google Calendar. Phew!

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-calendar-scroll-di/nghndfiaocgpmcbeafglhknklfgddebe

As a side note, here's an interesting bit of debugging by Peter Torelli which clearly shows it's just lazy coding in GCal: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/HeZb8Wv8X5k

Comment: All must-have plugin like this one should have its functionality embedded into the product